# Haskell List Comprehension order elements/tuples

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

I'm currently learning Haskell and am an absolute beginner when it comes to FP.

Right now I'm trying different stuff with list comprehensions.

```
 listComprehension  = [(a,b,c) | a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- ys, even c, c == a+b] ++
                      [(a,b,c) | a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- ys, even c, c == a-b]
                      where xs = [1..4]; ys = [(-100)..100]
```

So why not say:

```
 listComprehension  = [(a,b,c) | a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- ys, even c, c == a+b || c == a-b]
                      where xs = [1..4]; ys = [(-100)..100]
```

?

I want the elements to be ordered exactly like my first example.
I want all elements where c = a+b and then all elements where c = a-b.

Notice that in my 2nd code the order is not what I would like to have. I can't seem to figure out how I order things in a list comprehension, specially when I have tuples..

Thank you!

Comment: Your second list compression is much more efficient than most. Its output is a very short list.-- Separate the + & - in the very short list with [(a,b,c) |(a,b,c)<-lc1, c==a+b]++ [(a,b,c) |(a,b,c)<-lc1, c==a-b] where lc1 is the output of your fast list compression. OR simpler  `partition (\(a,b,c) -> c == a+b) lc1`produces both lists in a tuple.– fp_mora 22 hours ag

Comment: Also, it is superfluous to select values from `y` when you can just set them. The results are the same. `let xs = [1..4] in     [(a,b,c) | a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- [(a-b),(a+b)], even c]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Choose between functions `(+),(-)` in the first generator.

```
listComprehension =
   [(a,b,c) | f <- [(+),(-)], a <- xs, b <- xs, c <- ys, even c, c == f a b ]
   where xs = [1..4]; ys = [(-100)..100]
```

By the way, this is an inefficient approach. Instead of trying every `c <- ys`, we should instead `let c = f a b` and then check whether `-100 <= c && c <= 100` (and evenness). We make the code ~200 times faster, in this way.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect! I wasn't aware you could use a function as a generator in a list comprehension.

Comment: @chi Just out of curiosity, how have you measured ~200x speed up?

Comment: @Marcel Of course, even if you couldn't use a function, you could still achieve the same effect with normal data; e.g. `[(a,b,c) | useAddition <- [False, True], ..., c == if useAddition then a + b else a - b]`. The real insight here is to put the things you want to vary slowest as the first generators.

Comment: Ok thats nice to know, too. This will definitely help me at some point. Thanks again!

Comment: @jaroslawj Doesn't look measured, just estimated: it does 200 fewer evenness checks and comparisons for every combination of f, a and b.

Comment: @jaroslawj It is indeed an estimate: the original code tries all values `c` in `[-100..100]` and then checks if  `c == f a b`. Testing only _one_ value for `c`, instead of 200, should be much faster (even if maybe not 200x faster).

Comment: @Marcel Remember that, in a functional language, functions are "first-class" value, like integers, lists, pairs, etc. Variables can be bound to any value, including functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have used alternate functions ([even,odd]) in list comprehensions before. I was not always satisfied that they were most efficient. The drawback, I saw, was that they would make two or more passes through the source list. For this, I opted for a different approach, though, efficiency is not much of a consideration with smaller sets of data.

This is what I wrote

```
lc xs ys = [[(a,b,c)|(a,b,c)<-ls,c==a+b] ++ [(a,b,c)|(a,b,c)<-ls,c==a-b]]
           where ls = [(a,b,c)| a<-xs, b<-xs, c<-ys, even c]
```

This was faster than your original function and faster than the other answer. What was more striking is that it used much less memory than either.

It is one thing to select values from a long list and another to just set them from generated values.

```
lc xs = [(a,b,c)|a<-xs,b<-xs,c<-[(a-b),(a+b)],even c]
partition (\(a,b,c) -> c == a+b) lc [1..4]
```